# How to use DaggerAppCompatActivity in MainActivity

Tags: android, dagger

I have tried to use dagger in my project, but the code can not be compiled if I replace AppCompatActivity with DaggerAppCompatActivity in my MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {  // how to use dagger in MainActivity?

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to replace AppCompatActivity with DaggerAppCompatActivity. Read this: https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-for-dummies-in-kotlin-with-one-page-simple-code-project-618a5f9f2fe8 Straight forward tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

this is a good sample for use `dagger`

https://github.com/iammert/dagger-android-injection